# Use function argument as key/value

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, dry

I have the following function that takes key, value and callback as arguments. The function has been wrote with DRY principles in mind and the purpose of the function is to do a lookup to an Elasticsearch endpoint using the key/values that are passed in to the function.

```
function foo (key, value, callback) {
    client.search({
        index: 'foo',
        type: 'bar',
        body: {
            query: {
                term: {
                    key: value
                }
            }
        }
    } ... )
}
```

The problem I seem to be having is that `key` doesn't get interpreted correctly and instead of `key` being the argument value, the actual value of 'key' is used in the query to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
function foo (key, value, callback) {
  var query = {
    index: 'foo',
    type: 'bar',
    body: {
      query: {
        term: {
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  query.body.query.term[key] = value;

  client.search(query);
}
```

Or if you use ES6, you can do like this

```js
function foo (key, value, callback) {
  client.search( {
    index: 'foo',
    type: 'bar',
    body: {
      query: {
        term: {
          [key]: value
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```